# Zoom in as \spy does to produce very huge characters in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to output "very big" (many times larger than \Huge) characters in a TikZ picture ? Toying with an example file from http://www.texample.net/, I was able to produce some piece of code
going in the right direction, using the \spy command (see below), but this is still rather far from what I want : I just want to "very big" characters displayed, I do not care about the "ordinary" characters temporarily used and I do not want clipping. Any ideas ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{center}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%
\usetikzlibrary{spy,arrows}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   [ x=.5mm, y=.5mm,
      font={\sffamily},
      station/.style={fill=gray},
      hut/.style={fill=lightgray},
      cluster/.style={fill=yellow!30, rounded corners=2pt},
      road/.style={fill=blue!10},
      calorimeter/.style={fill=green!30},
      tracker/.style={fill=red!30},
      hisparc/.style={fill=red, rounded corners=.15pt},
      hisparcgps/.style={fill=red},
      axis/.style={gray,very thick,->,>=stealth'},
      ruler/.style={gray,|<->|,>=stealth'},
      spy using outlines={red, circle, magnification=4, size=25 * 4,
                          connect spies}
    ]
   \coordinate (A) (3,3);
   \draw (A) node {\Huge BIG};
  \spy on (A) in node at (12,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\node[scale=10] {This is Huger};`

Comment: @percusse given the OPs comment on my answer, I guess there's a tick waiting for you if you make that an answer:(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done.

Comment: @percusse :-) :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you are using scalable fonts (eg more or less any font other than default computer modern, or add `fix-cm` package for scalable computer modern)  then anywhere, not only for tikz but elsewhere you can go

```
 \fontsize{5in}{6in}\selectfont
```

to get big letters of any size you want.

---

In particular to TikZ, you can scale the node to get larger letters. This is simply done by adding `scale=<number>` option to the node, e.g.,

```
\node[scale=10] {This is Huger};
```

Or if you are working in a scope and wish to have the nodes respecting the scale then you can add `transform shape` option

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) node[left,transform shape] {A} node[right] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: A TikZ answer! *gasp* `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda check the edit history

Comment: it's a trap! `:)`